# How to prevent subscribe form to appear again in the index page after i submit the form

Tags: php, laravel

I have an index page that have subscriber form. when the user entered their email address, the user redirect again to the index page, and the form appear again

So, how to disable this, 
i have some ideas but not works, if i can use cookies or sessions or jquery? Currently i am using laravel 5.4

i tried this, but doesn't work

in my controller

```
public function postEmailPosts(Request $request){


    $this->validate($request,[
        'email' => 'required|unique:sub_scribers',
    ]);

    $cookie = Cookie::make('submit',1, 60);

    SubScriber::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->back();

}
```

and in my index i have this code

```
@if(Session::get('submit')==1)

    <div class="subscribe-me text-center">
        <h1>كن دائما مع أخبار البادية</h1>
        <h2>إشترك في القائمة البريدية لمجلة البادية</h2>
        <a href="#close" class="sb-close-btn"><img class="<img-responsive></img-responsive>" src="src/images/others/close-button.png" alt="" /></a>
        <form action="{{ route('email.subscribe') }}" method="post" id="popup-subscribe-form" name="subscribe-form">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><img src="src/images/others/icon-message.png" alt="" /></span>
                {!! Form::email('email',null,['placeholder'=>'إدخل البريد اﻹلكتروني']) !!}
                <button type="submit" name="subscribe">أذهب</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="_token"  value="{{ Session::token() }}">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>  <!--/.subscribe-me-->
    @endif
```

thank you at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public function postEmailPosts(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request,[
        'email' => 'required|unique:sub_scribers',
    ]);

    SubScriber::create($request->all());
    // using ->withCookie
    return redirect()->back()->withCookie('submit',1, 60);
}
```

and in your index

```
@if(Cookie::get("submit")!=1)

    <div class="subscribe-me text-center">
        <h1>كن دائما مع أخبار البادية</h1>
        <h2>إشترك في القائمة البريدية لمجلة البادية</h2>
        <a href="#close" class="sb-close-btn"><img class="<img-responsive></img-responsive>" src="src/images/others/close-button.png" alt="" /></a>
        <form action="{{ route('email.subscribe') }}" method="post" id="popup-subscribe-form" name="subscribe-form">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><img src="src/images/others/icon-message.png" alt="" /></span>
                {!! Form::email('email',null,['placeholder'=>'إدخل البريد اﻹلكتروني']) !!}
                <button type="submit" name="subscribe">أذهب</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="_token"  value="{{ Session::token() }}">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>  <!--/.subscribe-me-->
@endif
```

Comment: Great to hear, would love if you accept my answer :)